# Why some blade is called "beaver blade"

Tags: medical

I found the term *beaver blade* used in veterinary article.

Could you please explain why the blade is called *beaver blade*: is it related to an animal, or something else? How does it related to the shape of the blade?

*Update*

I am not sure it is brand related issue; look at this non medical picture—

[image: image of a "Beaver Blade" for a circular saw]

For those thinking it is branding/off-topic  look at [this link and picture of BEAVER KNIFE](http://missslilu.zoomshare.com/album/SHEMOIXEDE%20GENACVALE/images/a055c46c444b55aab5941390bc99bcef_11589393500/:album).

Comment: It’s a brand name.

Comment: @tchrist could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Beaver® has been manufacturing high-quality, trusted surgical blades since 1932. Beaver-Visitec International provides a wide variety of Beaver® knives and blades for ophthalmic and specialty surgical procedures.](http://www.beaver-visitec.com/brands/beaver.cfm)

Comment: @tchrist what do you think about this - http://www.drpower.com/power-equipment/trimmer-mowers/accessories/12in-beaver-blade-complete-pkg.axd

Comment: @tchrist: Jinks! (Jinx?)

Comment: That saw blade is probably trying to make some analogy about how this blade chews through wood as eagerly as a beaver.

Comment: @Jim thanks for the idea... I hope to find some more precise answer :)

Comment: You won't find a more precise answer unless you go to the manufacturer directly and ask, "Why did you name your saw blade a 'beaver' blade."  They're the only ones that can provide an authoritative answer to that kind of question.

Comment: @Jim I find some med article comparing Beaver blade to Diamond blade. If it was just a brand name, one could not know what Beaver blade actually means (multiple variants should exist)

Comment: I guarantee it's a brand name.  There may just be multiple companies in non-competing industries that each use "Beaver" as part of their brand or trademark.  The use of Beaver on the saw blade is definitely part of the brand/logo.  Notice how the logo includes what looks like a beaver head in front with fur that resembles a saw blade on the back.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing at the reason behind a company's product naming decision.

Comment: @Jim I thought that beaver is related to the armor and not to any brand naming. I met article just saying "we used beaver blade bla-bla-bla", this is why I am not sure you're right

Comment: Beaver and Diamond are both brand names for surgical blades. It may be confusing because there are also such things as 'diamond blades' that are sawblades used for tile, stone, metal, etc. and the brand of Beaver sawblades like the one pictured above are a brand for wood-cutting saw blades. This Beaver brand is not the same as the surgical brand.

Comment: @KitFox blade and knife are close, are they? http://missslilu.zoomshare.com/album/SHEMOIXEDE%20GENACVALE/images/a055c46c444b55aab5941390bc99bcef_11589393500/%3aalbum

Comment: Yes, a blade is long, flat, and sharp and describes that part of the knife (not the handle). Blades are often sold separately from handles for things like surgical instruments because the blades are replaced rather than sharpened.

Comment: Please make up your mind what you're asking about. The original question asked about *beaver blade* in a veterinary context. It's hardly likely the trademark name of the buzz-saw blade you've now added is relevant to the original question.

Comment: Can you link to the article you read this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know the term, but comparing [this picture](http://www.surgical-instrument-pictures.com/instrument-index-beaver-handle.html) of something called a "beaver blade handle"...

[image: Photo of a metallic rod labeled "beaver blade handle" from surgical-instrument-pictures.com]

...and [this picture](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.riverfronttimes.com%2Fgutcheck%2FBeaver_Tail_1.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ar15.com%2Farchive%2Ftopic.html%3Fb%3D5%26f%3D49%26t%3D102401&h=456&w=600&tbnid=5l5b0GSeJnv-aM%3A&zoom=1&docid=YzR8opSHStbAxM&ei=0n-0U87rB8KwOaLkgZgC&tbm=isch&ved=0CDEQMygQMBA&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=841&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20) of a beaver's tail...

[image: Photo of the central size of an undissected beaver tail]

...I'm tempted to think it refers to the [knurling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knurling) *(a manufacturing process, typically conducted on a lathe, whereby a diamond-shaped (criss-cross) pattern is cut or rolled into metal)*.

But it's probably relevant to note that *[**Beaver®**](http://www.beaver-visitec.com/brands/beaver.cfm) has been manufacturing high-quality, trusted surgical blades since 1932.*

---

EDIT: I'll leave the above for historical reasons, but since someone downvoted I spent a couple more minutes looking into this. Here's [a relevant definition](http://www.entusa.com/tympanoplasty_instruments.htm) for OP's (original) context...

> Some surgeons prefer to cut the ear canal skin flap sharply using *a beaver blade or sickle knife*
>    - see right picture.

...and here's the picture...

[image: Photo of the beaver blade, a small, hooked metal tip]

(And no - I've no idea why they call it a "beaver" blade, though "sickle knife" is obvious!)

EDIT2: Okay - I'll hazard a guess it's because beavers' teeth are *curved*, a bit like a sickle.

Comment: nice answer, for now I am voting up. Later will probably accept it, but want to see other answers...

Comment: what do you think about this http://www.drpower.com/power-equipment/trimmer-mowers/accessories/12in-beaver-blade-complete-pkg.axd

Comment: can you find any connection to the teeth of the beaver?

Comment: @Ilan: Your 12" circular saw "Beaver Blade®" looks like a trademarked *single product* (I can find any similar blades using that terminology). So I'd guess that's a reference to the teeth ripping through wood like a beaver's teeth. But actually, when I searched for **circular saw Beaver Blade** I saw more than one item referring to the fact that ideally you *don't* want a saw blade that makes such rough cuts they look like they've been chewed through by a beaver.

Comment: I have found a right answer - the beaver knife or blade is called after its sickle shape which is exact analogy to beaver teeth.

Answer (score 0):

American beavers are famous (in real life) for chewing through young trees on the banks of the streams where they live and constructing dams with the felled saplings and branches. So when people in the United States think of beavers, they think of the kind of exaggerated wood-cutting prowess shown at 5:59 of this 1931 Walt Disney "Silly Symphony" cartoon, "[The Busy Beavers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zw4ZiGK_ug)." (Cartoon termites and cartoon woodpeckers are capable of similar prodigies, but they are perceived as less benignant.) What company wouldn't want to name its saw blades after an animal capable (in cartoons) of that kind of performance?

I believe that the product name is based on precisely that level of familiarity with beavers and their incredible sawmill-like wood-cutting abilities.

Comment: I should perhaps also note that beavers are renowned in American culture for their eagerness and their busyness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found a right one - the beaver knife or blade is called after its sickle shape which is exact analogy to beaver teeth.

Comment: @Ilan: That's probably the reason - but it's not an *exact* analogy. The cutting edge of a beaver's tooth is the same as a human incisor - the flat edge at right angles to the length. A *sickle* (similar to *scythe*) has the cutting edge *along the curved length*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers :) I don't think we should overthink this question... at least, it is not off topic